# PostSharp is continually asking for "Some NuGet packages may need to be installed"

Tags: postsharp

PostSharp is already installed to the package, or at least it's already been attempted to be added multiple times.

Instead, it warns on every compilation, and on top of that "add PostSharp to project" doesn't disappear after the same action is executed, leading me to believe that the "Add PostSharp" action isn't completing properly.

- How can this be manually installed to get around this OR
- Can we just fix PostSharp so the add issue is removed (eg the bug is fixed)

Answer (score 1):

You can validate which of your projects have PostSharp NuGet package installed with the "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." dialog box. You can also try to re-install the packages using the same dialog and see if it fixes the issue.

The "Some NuGet packages..." PostSharp dialog box can be disabled with "Do not show this dialog" check-box. The option is also available in "PostSharp" -> "Options" -> "Advanced" -> "Disable NuGet dependency verification before build".

Normally, the project that has PostSharp NuGet package installed should not appear in this dialog.